# Angular http request how to convert Json Object into an object Array

Tags: json, angular, http, get

i wanted to simulate a http request by reading an Json File and its stored data. Here is how i tryed it

Data.json:

```
{ "jsonData": {


"data1": [{
   "age": "18",
   "name": "bernd",
   "gender": "1"
}],

"data2": [{ "age": "18", "name": "bernd", "gender": "1"},
    { "age": "18", "name": "bernd", "gender": "1"},
    { "age": "15", "name": "bernd", "gender": "1"},
    { "age": "18", "name": "marting", "gender": "1"},
    { "age": "25", "name": "bernd", "gender": "1"},
    { "age": "29", "name": "bernd", "gender": "1"},
    { "age": "18", "name": "mike", "gender": "1"},
    { "age": "45", "name": "bernd", "gender": "1"},
    { "age": "18", "name": "bernd", "gender": "1"}
],

"data3": [{ "age": "18", "name": "mike", "gender": "1"},
    { "age": "18", "name": "monika", "gender": "2"},
    { "age": "18", "name": "martin", "gender": "1"},
    { "age": "18", "name": "monika", "gender": "2"},
    { "age": "18", "name": "monika", "gender": "2"},
    { "age": "18", "name": "monika", "gender": "2"},
    { "age": "18", "name": "bernd", "gender": "1"},
    { "age": "18", "name": "bernd", "gender": "1"},
    { "age": "18", "name": "lisa", "gender": "2"}
]}}
```

and a service which recieves the data

data.service:

```
getServers() {
return this.http.get('../assets/Data.json')
.subscribe((res: Response) => {
  this.testData = res.json().data2;
} );}
```

The plan is to get for example the "data2" object Array into "this.testData". I tryed different versions of http.get, but just managed to get the Json object without successfully converting it into a object[].

I would really appreciate your help guys.

Comment: shouldn't it be `res.json().jsonData.data2` ?

Comment: Seems like it was the problem... Thanks for your help!